# Cannot Resolve addTextChangedListener Symbol Android

Tags: android

```
String x;
double z,y;
EditText first;
EditText second;
EditText result;
EditText Et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ch1);
Et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged() {

    }
});
```

Hi I shared my code. I'm trying to use onTextChanged feature, my xml id is ch1 of Edittext.. why it's showing Cannot Resolve addTextChangedListener Symbol ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move this code in the onCreate() method.

```
EditText Et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ch1);
Et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {

        }
});
```

You have to keep all methods from the TextWatcher class, don't delete anything.

Comment: I got another error.. please check I post my own answer.. refresh the page.. Thanks

Comment: I solved the Error by using this before find....
    EditText ch1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.ch1);

Comment: I edited the post, check it out. Also you posted the logs as an answer! don't to that, you need to edit your post and include it there instead of posting it. Don't forget to accept the answer if it help you solve the problem.